# Put result from lapply with different columns to one data frame

Tags: r, lapply, rbind

I'm dealing with a data set and want to have some descriptive statistics of some variables and put them in just one data frame.
I can deal with situations like this :

```
dt<-data.frame('X1'=rnorm(10),
           'X2'=rnorm(10))
temp<-do.call(rbind, lapply(dt, summary))
```

And also situation like this:

```
dt<-data.frame('X1'=rnorm(10),
           'X2'=rnorm(10))
dt[1,2]<-NA
dt[2,1]<-NA
temp<-do.call(rbind, lapply(dt, summary))
```

But when it comes to situation like below, I can't:

```
dt<-data.frame('X1'=rnorm(10),
           'X2'=rnorm(10))
dt[1,2]<-NA
temp<-do.call(rbind, lapply(dt, summary))
```

when some variables contain NA while some does not, the result from **lapply** of different variables would have different columns :

```
> lapply(dt, summary)
$X1
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.7821000 -0.2881000 -0.0003675  0.3195000  0.8114000  2.0230000 

$X2
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
-1.336000 -0.604000 -0.005283  0.008491  0.784300  1.407000         1
```

in which case  `rbind` won't work any more. I do realize that there is `rbnd.fill` that could do row bind when data frames have different columns but transfer the result of each variable into data frame then combine them by `rbind.fill` would be  some kind of tedious and I do believe there is a one command solution given the power R have.

Hope some one could help me on this , your time and knowledge would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `rbind.fill` with `tidy` from `broom` package and get it in one go, i.e.

```
plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(dt, function(i) broom::tidy(summary(i))))
#    minimum         q1     median        mean         q3   maximum na
#1 -1.621968 -0.7001894 -0.2062857  0.06791479  0.5987752 2.4195609 NA
#2 -2.061762 -1.3925008 -1.1702881 -0.94991206 -0.9249380 0.6052219  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sotos, a wonderful solution works perfectly. I'll take it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

An answer using the *tidyverse* way, ie `purrr` mainly :

```r
dt<-data.frame('X1'=rnorm(10),
               'X2'=rnorm(10))
dt[1,2]<-NA

library(purrr)
library(broom)
dt %>%
  map(., summary) %>%
  map_df(broom::tidy)
#>     minimum         q1     median       mean        q3  maximum na
#> 1 -0.798480  0.5869163 0.89381256  0.9626454 1.6942529 2.218769 NA
#> 2 -1.331122 -1.0149286 0.05946167 -0.1562312 0.5235401 1.061640  1
```

For what you are doing, you can also be interested in the ongoing work about `skimr` package by ropensci community. It is not on CRAN yet but on github. It aims at simplify summary statistic use, compatible with *tidyverse* approach

```r
# devtools::install_github("ropenscilabs/skimr")
dt %>% skimr::skim()
#> Numeric Variables
#> # A tibble: 2 x 13
#>     var    type missing complete     n       mean        sd       min
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1    X1 numeric       0       10    10  0.9626454 0.9001430 -0.798480
#> 2    X2 numeric       1        9    10 -0.1562312 0.8539957 -1.331122
#> # ... with 5 more variables: `25% quantile` <dbl>, median <dbl>, `75%
#> #   quantile` <dbl>, max <dbl>, hist <chr>
```

Comment: Thanks @cderv, the first solution works perfectly. Did not test the second yet. I'll rise it up  though can't make it an answer.

Comment: Wanted to mention that skimr is now on CRAN.  It has a function skim_to_wide() that returns a single data frame where the statistics that don't apply for a data type are set to NA.  All of the variables are character though, so they are formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using only the `plyr` package, you can use the coercion `as` family of functions together with `plyr::rbind.fill` to accomplish what you want with code similar you your original post. `plyr::rbind.fill` expects a data.frame, so we convert the output of `summary` (a named vector) first to a list and then to a data.frame using `as.data.frame.list`.

```
do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(dt, function(x) as.data.frame.list(summary(x))))
```

This returns

```
        Min.   X1st.Qu.     Median        Mean    X3rd.Qu.      Max. NA.s
1 -1.3228095 -0.9366220  0.3869426  0.05838389  0.85474059 1.1721839   NA
2 -0.8421435 -0.5083617 -0.4801625 -0.29357112 -0.02549078 0.4506287    1
```

Comment: Thanks @Imo, elegant one line solution. Never aware of this kind of operation.

Comment: You can see the vast set of the `as.` family of functions in R by typing `as.` in the console and then hit the TAB key.